# Prove that the class of Turing Decidable Languages is strictly larger than class of Context Free Languages

Tags: context-free-grammar, turing-machines, pumping-lemma

Prove that the class of Turing decidable languages is strictly larger than the class of context free languages. (Give a language that is Turing decidable, but which violates the pumping lemma for context free languages).

I don't know how to solve this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Can you think of a set $A$ of finite strings which is

- Easy to describe (this is informal, but it's better to start informally than to look for something which you know fits the definition of "decidable" - in practice, most things which are "easily describable" will be decidable), but
- Doesn't satisfy the pumping lemma?

In fact, probably *any example you've seen* of a set of strings not satisfying the pumping lemma is Turing decidable . . .

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @BricePetty Have you had any exercises of the form "Show that --- is not a CFL by showing it fails the pumping lemma?"

Comment: yes, I have. I just don't understand the connection

Comment: @BricePetty OK, so take your favorite example of a language L which is not a CFL, since it fails the pumping lemma. If you can show L is Turing decidable, then you're done.

Comment: Okay, I have chosen the language L = even length binary string where the first half of the string is the same sequence as he second half of the string. By pumping lemma, I have proven that this language is not a CFL. Now, how would I go about showing this string is turing decidable?

Comment: @BricePetty Write a Turing machine to decide it! (I presume you're not allowed to just say "Church's thesis".)